# Misspelling of 'hand independance' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Am I the only one that thinks the tag for [hand-independance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independance) is misspelled?  That it should be [hand-independence](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independence) with an `e`?  Can this be corrected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes independence is spelled with an *e* between the d and the n instead of an *a*. I just did a quick, dirty fix by making [hand-independence](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independence) and switching out the [hand-independance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independance) tag and marking it do not use.

Removing [hand-independance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independance) is doable, but since it has something in it's wiki it will need moderator attention to remove.

Comment: I merged the old tag into the new without synonymizing, so it's gone now.

Comment: @MatthewRead thanks in the future if something like this were to happen again would it be better to wait for a mod or just create the correct tag like I did?

Comment: Either way works, you didn't do any harm but it might be simpler/cleaner to let us handle it. I've been asking for years for high-rep users to have more control over tags but in the meantime most stuff is left to mods.